# Does the command execute automatically when setting it to a variable?

Tags: shell-script, command-substitution

I'm getting familiar with all about Linux & shell/bash scripting.

I'm configuring a backup script & it will compress an entire directory.
I want to know if I have to print the variable where the command that will compress will be allocated or only by setting it to the variable will execute it?

I have this:

```
x1=$(tar cfz "/dir_destination" "/dir_to_compress/")
echo "$x1"
```

I'm wondering if I could safely remove 'echo' line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$()` syntax is called [command substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/cmdsubst) and the shell treats it by first executing the command inside the parentheses then assigning its stdout (with trailing newlines removed) to `x1`.

In other words, the command is executed even before you `echo "$x1"`.

Comment: Perfect, so, if I understood the links you put above, It's more recommended to use quotes despite I'm not using any coma in the command? Or quotes are necessary for x1 to execute the command?

Comment: @tachomi The quotes are necessary in case the output of the command has any whitespace. Without quotes, Bash would consider that the command's output up to the first whitespace character is what you are trying to assign to `x1` and it will consider what comes after as additional commands.

Comment: So while 'tar' command commonly doesn't have an output, quotes are not necessary down here. Will be necessary for this kind of usage?:
    print=$(echo nice to meet you) - WRONG
    print="$(echo nice to meet you)" - RIGHT

Comment: @tachomi Yes, if the command has no output, the quotes are unnecessary, but so is the command substitution. What do you think to gain by assigning a null string to `x1`?

Comment: Only the creation of the .tar.gz file to then send it using scp to a backup server :D

Comment: @tachomi In that case, just execute the `tar` command. Why assign its output to `x1`?

Comment: The quotes are not necessary here as we're not in list context. You're assigning to a scalar variable, so no splitting+globbing here as `x1` can only hold one string value. It would be different with an array variable (`x1=($(...))`). In any case, the quotes don't harm. It's better do add them when not necessary than to forget them when they're needed.

Comment: Oh you're right, I was taking anybody's script as an example to do mine and it has that line, but I don't have to assign that command to be executed. Thank you very much Joseph, I'm just familiarizing with all this stuff :S

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thanks for the correction. Editing the answer accordingly.